# Optimal way to get closest element

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, min

I got the following function to get closest object to user location. Is there any other way? I want to make my code more clear. Is it possible to resolve this problem using `NSPredicate`? The object `MyZone` contains `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

```
- (MyZone *)closestBaseAgglomeration {
    CLLocation *userLocation = self.locationManager.location;
    NSArray *zoneArr = //Get zone array here
    CLLocationDistance minDist = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    MyZone *closestZone = nil;
    for (int it=0; it<zoneArr.count; it++) {
        MyZone *curZone = [zoneArr objectAtIndex:it];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D curCoordinate = curZone.coordinateRegion.center;
        CLLocation *curLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:curCoordinate.latitude longitude:curCoordinate.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance actDist = [curLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
        if (minDist > actDist) {
            closestZone = curZone;
            minDist = actDist;
        }
    }
    return closestZone;
}
```

Comment: Looks fairly clear and is pretty much the only way if you are arranging your objects in a 1-D array.

Comment: You could change the returned type to `ELBaseAgglomeration`, as this is what you are actually returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a call to the method indexOfObjectPassingTest and pass in a block that selects the object who's distance is closest to the current location. I don't know if you would consider that clearer or not.

If you are doing this repeatedly, or on a large array of locations, then the overhead of creating CLLocation objects for every location will become significant. You might want to add a CLLocation property to your MyZone class and save your object's locations in the CLLocation instead of using lat/long values. That way you could avoid creating CLLocation objects for every entry in your array every time you want to find the nearest object. CLLocation conforms to NSCoding, so you can save it to a fail reasonably easily...

Answer (score 2):

To make it a bit more readable you could change your for loop to something like

```
for (MyZone *curZone in zoneArr.count) {
..
}
```

and perhaps move the distance calculation and conversion between CLLocationCoordinate2D and CLLocation into a new method of your MyZone class.

Comment: Agreed. For...in syntax is an improvement. (+1)